# Rhythmbox import error in 12.04

Tags: rhythmbox, ffmpeg

Rhythmbox is not able to install the MPEG-4 plugin when I import mp4 files into it.
It identifies the plugin(Gstreamer), but fails to install it citing package dependency errors as following:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.32.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.31) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.16) but 1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                           Depends: libpostproc-extra-52 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libswscale-extra-2 (>= 4:0.7.3-1) but 4:0.8.1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Unmet dependencies for Media Players](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131639/unmet-dependencies-for-media-players)

Please try `sudo apt-get install -f` at the Terminal, as suggested in the above link.

Comment: I had already tried that and it is not helping. Following is the output:

deep@deep:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: May be related to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/+bug/971012). If you can manually install ffmpeg, vlc, it should also install most of the codecs. Use ``sudo apt-get install vlc ffmpeg``.

Comment: I had vlc already installed, and this ffmpeg installation went through as well. Nevertheless, that particular plugin installation still fails.